# Error while executing process .../ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

Why do I get next error? p.s. there is no any `ndk-build` folder at `ndk-bundle` what does it mean?

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/user/JNI/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/user/JNI/app/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=/home/user/JNI/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/user/JNI/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
```

in my `~/.bashrc` I have next:

```
export NDK=/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
export PATH=$PATH:$NDK
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Android/Sdk
```

**UPDATE**

from TERMINAL:

```
user@user-X556UQK:~/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle$ ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/user/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/JNIINVOKEFFMPEG1/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/user/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/JNIINVOKEFFMPEG1/app/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=/home/user/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/JNIINVOKEFFMPEG1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/user/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/JNIINVOKEFFMPEG1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n
Android NDK: /home/user/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/JNIINVOKEFFMPEG1/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'ffmpeg/android/arm' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
/home/user/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/JNIINVOKEFFMPEG1/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:14: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the bottom line is, when you see this message in Android Studio,

```
Error while executing process …/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {…}
```

and you don't know what really caused the error, you should try to run exactly same command with exactly same arguments in terminal. The output may give you a reasonable hint.

Specifically in this case, the error message from Android NDK explained which file (`/home/user/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/JNIINVOKEFFMPEG1/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk`) and which line (**14**) was in trouble, and even explains what you can do to fix:

> define **NDK_MODULE_PATH** in your environment to let NDK find the *module* `ffmpeg/android/arm`

Comment: For users with similar issues: It's better to use CMake instead of legacy NDK build now. It's much easier to understand, configure

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work in android studio.

In packages,select  the folder which has ndk files , delete the intermediates generated (including .build and .externalndkbuild)and clean the project
if requires try invalidate cache and restart in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Launched in the terminal. Got this answer:

> Android NDK: Could not find application project directory!
>
> Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.

As a result, the reason was Maximum Path Length Limitation (260 characters).

By adding this code to build.gradle (app), the project builds:

```
allprojects {
 if (Os.isFamily (Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
     buildDir = "$ {projectDir} /../../../../ build"
 }
}
```