# Android Studio ndk-build finish with non-zero value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I updated my Android Studio to 3.1.3 yesterday and then the old projects previously working with NDK fail to work after that and give me this response:

```
Process 'command '/Users/new-User/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

**What I have tried:**

1. Undo all the .cpp and .h changes and run again -- still this error
2. Find an older version of the project that guarantee to work and run it -- also get this error
3. Check the directory name see if it has white spaces -- no white spaces
4. Check the NDK directory -- no change

This is the part that is related to NDK in build.gradle:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine "/Users/new-User/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk',
            'NDK_LOG=1'
}
```

Also inside cradle.properties, I have:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Could someone point out the problem for me please? Is the update of Android Studio breaking the project or some of my unintentional actions breaking it?

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399551/192373 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50953301/192373 and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952779/192373